# WPF: Waiting for an ItemContainerGenerator to have its containers ready

Tags: wpf

I'm writing a WPF control that contains an ItemsControl. The control adds and removes items based on certain user actions. Once an item has been added, the control needs to access a FrameworkElement inside the ItemTemplate instance that was just created.

I'm using `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex` to do this. I also get a ContentPresenter back, but it is empty: it appears it takes a few milliseconds on a separate thread to instantiate the template objects.

I read that I need to use `ItemContainerGenerator.Status` to determine whether or not the containers are fully created, so I wrote the following method:

```
private async Task<TextBox> GetMainInputControl(int index)
    {
        // _selectedItemsEditor is the ItemsControl inside my main control that contains the items
        var evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        _selectedItemsEditor.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var status = _selectedItemsEditor.ItemContainerGenerator.Status;
            if (status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated || status == GeneratorStatus.Error)
            {
                evt.Set();
            }
        };

        ContentPresenter container = null;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var status = _selectedItemsEditor.ItemContainerGenerator.Status;
            if (status == GeneratorStatus.GeneratingContainers
                || status == GeneratorStatus.NotStarted)
            {
                evt.WaitOne();
            }

            container =
                _selectedItemsEditor.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ContentPresenter;
        });

        return container?.ContentTemplate.FindName("PART_ItemEditorMainInput", container) as TextBox;
    }
```

I know that there are a few things I need to fix here, but mostly, it just doesn't work, because `_selectedItemsEditor.ItemContainerGenerator.Status` immediately returns `GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated`, so the code doesn't wait - but then the code `container?.ContentTemplate.FindName` throws an exception indicating that the container is NOT ready.

How can I make this work, or alternatively use a better way of achieving this?

Comment: The `ItemContainerGenerator` return null for items that are not currently visible. Maybe this is also the problem why the content presenter is empty.

Comment: @DominicJonas - no, the items are visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code looks like you're trying to access ui controls on a background thread. So I'm not at all surprised it doesn't work.

There are two approaches I would consider.
You could defer your code so it waits until the dispatcher ( the ui thread essentially ) has done it's stuff for whatever you just asked it to do.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() => 
{  
   // Your code which is to run after the items are rendered

}), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

Or
You could force the layout process so you make the items do their thing. This will potentially lock the ui up whilst it's working. If the user clicks something and his obvious intent is to wait for layout to update or there's not so much going on then this won't be a problem.
You could just call .UpdateLayout() on your control.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually, the background thread is not an issue here. You can test that by adding the line Thread.Sleep(10) before calling ContainerFromIndex - this makes all the code work perfectly (except that it's stupid to wait for a random time of exactly 10ms). But calling ContainerFromIndex using Dispatcher.Invoke is a very smart idea. Thank you! By the way, can I call this using DispatcherPriority.Loaded? that does occur after layout and rendering...

Comment: If it works then I would think that means you're not actually running on a background thread or you're not really using any ui object. Shrug.   Avoid fixed times, code runs at different speeds on different machines. It'd be unreliable.  I suggested contextidle because it's the safest option. Everything that'll happen due to your change must have happened by then. If loaded works for you then you could go with that. It's your app, I'm just throwing in suggestions as a break whilst writing my own.